# using phpseclib with net_ssh how to su to root using $ssh->exec

Tags: php, ssh, command-line-interface, phpseclib

So i need to execute one command but it will only run if i su to root (or sudo ) but I can't seem to figure out how to send the command to su to root

(i can log in and execute other commands with loginuser fine)

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html

My code as follows

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('255.255.255.255',22);
if (!$ssh->login('loginuser', 'fakepassword')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->read('[prompt]');
echo $ssh->write("su\n");
echo $ssh->read('Password:');
echo $ssh->write("rootfakepassword");
echo $ssh->read('[prompt]');
echo $ssh->exec('cc get_wireless_status');
?>
```

I've also tried using the exec command to do roughly the same thing with no luck

any suggestions?

current revision of the code (doesnt work)

```
<?php
    include('Net/SSH2.php');

    $ssh = new Net_SSH2('255.255.99.74',22);
    if (!$ssh->login('loginuser', 'password')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }

    echo $ssh->read('loginuser@intranet:/home/login >');
    $ssh->write("su\n");
    echo $ssh->read('Password:');
    $ssh->write("rootpassword\n");
    echo $ssh->read('intranet:/home/login #');
    $ssh->write("cc get_wireless_status\n");
    echo $ssh->read('[prompt]');
?>
```

putty text of log in

```
login as: loginuser
loginuser@255.255.99.74's password:
Last login: Thu Feb 14 13:57:16 2013 from infong1045.lxa.perfora.net


Sophos UTM
(C) Copyrights by Astaro and by others 2000-2012.
For more copyright information look at /doc/astaro-license.txt
or http://www.astaro.com/doc/astaro-license.txt

NOTE: Any modifications done by root will void your support.
      Please use WebAdmin for any configuration changes.

loginuser@intranet:/home/login > su
Password:
intranet:/home/login #
```

response from code on newest version

```
Last login: Thu Feb 14 14:00:00 2013 from 10.10.10.194 Sophos UTM (C) Copyrights by Astaro and by others 2000-2012. For more copyright information look at /doc/astaro-license.txt or http://www.astaro.com/doc/astaro-license.txt NOTE: Any modifications done by root will void your support. Please use WebAdmin for any configuration changes. loginuser@intranet:/home/login > Last login: Tue Feb 19 11:09:18 2013 from infong1045.lxa.perfora.net Sophos UTM (C) Copyrights by Astaro and by others 2000-2012. For more copyright information look at /doc/astaro-license.txt or http://www.astaro.com/doc/astaro-license.txt NOTE: Any modifications done by root will void your support. Please use WebAdmin for any configuration changes. loginuser@intranet:/home/login > su Password: intranet:/home/login # Last login: Tue Feb 19 11:09:23 2013 from infong1045.lxa.perfora.net Sophos UTM (C) Copyrights by Astaro and by others 2000-2012. For more copyright information look at /doc/astaro-license.txt or http://www.astaro.com/doc/astaro-license.txt NOTE: Any modifications done by root will void your support. Please use WebAdmin for any configuration changes. loginuser@intranet:/home/login > cc get_wireless_status -bash: /usr/local/bin/confd-client.plx: Permission denied loginuser@intranet:/home/login >
```

Comment: Do you get errors? Or is it hanging while waiting for the password?

Comment: Sorry it hangs for quiet some time and it will error out after 2-3 min but I didn't copy the error but itwas something like such and such timed out.

Comment: 'error out' Do you have an error message?

Comment: I gett this message:Gateway Time-out

The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.  When i check the ssh log on the router i see it has connected and logged inas "loginuser"

Comment: Hmmm. Thats a HTTP error message. Do you execute the script from command line or from a web page?

Comment: website...... I think the session is just timing out. If i do the same thing thing with echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');  It displays the correct text

Comment: Is this for an Astaro Security Gateway?

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
<?php
    include('Net/SSH2.php');

    $ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
    if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }

    echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
    $ssh->write("su\n");
    echo $ssh->read('Password:');
    $ssh->write("password\n");
    echo $ssh->read('username@username:~#');
    $ssh->write("cc get_wireless_status\n");
    echo $ssh->read('[prompt]');
?>
```

Comment: Your answer is better than mine - I didn't notice that the op was using exec for the last command. Nice catch!

Comment: thanks for your answer but it appears to do the same thing waiting on the server

Comment: do i need to match the read line to match the acutal username?
loginuser@intranet:/home/login >
loginuser@intranet:/home/login > su
Password:
intranet:/home/login #

Comment: Yes. It needs to match the prompt exactly. See http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#password,timeout,

Comment: ill test, Do i really need to read the prompt? or can i bypass that alltogether?

Comment: I modified the read sections to match but still nothing Maybe im missing something but i posted the output from putty in the original post

Comment: So where is it halting? Is it halting after the first read(), the second() or the third?

Comment: It's also possible, incidentally, that there are ANSI escape codes in the prompt that you're just not seeing. Like maybe the prompt isn't the standard gray text for example. To see if that's the case I'd need to take a look at your SSH logs, which can be gotten thusly: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#logging (in particular, make note of the define() and the $ssh->getLog())

Comment: I have no way to know where its haulting

Comment: Put an exit ('whatever'); after the first write(). If it's hanging after that it'll display.  If it's hanging before that it won't.  Then move the exit down (or up) line by line until you find out where it /is/ hanging.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    include('Net/SSH2.php');

    $ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
    if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }

    $ssh->setTimeout(5);
    echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
    $ssh->write("su\n");
    echo $ssh->read('Password:');
    $ssh->write("password\n");
    echo $ssh->read('username@username:~#');
    $ssh->write("cc get_wireless_status\n");
    echo $ssh->read('[prompt]');
?>
```

I modified your code snippet to include a setTimeout(). So if one call to read() is failing that call will timeout and echo out the data that it's gotten up to that point.

Comment: screen output is pasted at the bottom of my main question above  (thanks so much i feel like were getting closer)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do echo `$ssh->write("rootfakepassword\n");`

ie. note the \n.

When you're running the command in putty or whatever you have to hit enter. This fact would need to be reflected in what you're sending to the server via phpseclib as well.

Answer (score 0):

Su is not the way to go here. Instead, use *sudo*, while adding yourself to the */etc/sudoers* file with a *NOPASSWD* flag, and then simply issuing sudo commands. You can find out how to do this [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/168470).

Alternatively, you can use expect inside your phpseclib script in order to spawn a root shell (this is not recommended, and is a pretty dirty trick):

```
echo $ssh->exec('expect -c \'log_user 0; set timeout -1; spawn /bin/su; expect "Password:"; send "rootpassword\r"; expect "\r\n"; send "/usr/bin/id\r\n"; log_user 1; expect "uid=0"\'');
```

On the machine I am trying this on, I get the following output:

> /usr/bin/id
>
> root@machine:/home/user# /usr/bin/id uid=0(root) gid=0(root)
>   groups=0(root)

Again, this method is dirty and has a lot of unwanted output, which you could trim I guess, if you read a bit of *expect* [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect). Sorry for not providing you with a cleaner solution, but I am afraid this is as good as it can get.

Comment: this is on a work router, i don't want to alter the os in anyway